# boost::asio get client ip

Tags: c++, ip, boost-asio

I'm writing a server over TCP using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/). I'm trying to find a way to block connections outside localhost. Only thing I found is [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/protocols.html#boost_asio.overview.networking.protocols.tcp_servers). There is:

```
boost::asio::ip::host_name()
```

which returns "tomasz-lenovo-ideapad-Y530" (that's the name of my machine). How to get raw ip ("127.0.0.1" or "localhost") from it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the socket object that serve given connection.

```
std::cout << "Peer IP: " << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
```

FYI: If you want to prevent any connections from other machines, its enough to listen 127.0.0.1 and not listen other interfaces. To do this, you should create acceptor like this:

```
acceptor(io_service, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), "5555"));
```

This will listen 127.0.0.1 on port 5555 only

Comment: Thanks! So how can I change my code to listen to localhost only? Current code for accepting goes as follows:

    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    acceptor.accept(socket);